# Replacing words in more than 300 xml files

Tags: php, xml

I need to read 300 of XML files and replacing some words in these files, this is a project which is already running and reading XML's files.
I did the replacing by dividing these files into 10 files on 30 request for fixing this issue. The PHP coding is used for doing this fix.

Any other ideas to increase performance and time of execution ?!

Comment: You want us to improve the performance of code that we can't see, and whose current performance is unknown?

Comment: I feel the idea is not perfect, so i 'm asking about another idea to be more valuable and perfect in performance, (Analyzing idea before coding)

Comment: Yes, but we can't suggest "improvements" to something without a baseline.